# How can I convert my function to loop every 2 seconds until the results (response) are no longer null? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, for-loop

I have a block of code that I run and I want to loop every 2 seconds until the results (val1, val2, val3) are no longer null. How can I change and wrap this to do that?

```
        // get the data
      let theData = null;
      try {
        theData = await gRating.loadData(request_code)
      } catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex);
            respondWithError(res, 'API error', 500);
            return;
      }
```

the loadData function returns an array and stores it in theData that looks like this:

```
return [this.val1, this.val2, this.val3]
```

Comment: Use an interval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setInterval` and check if the `theData` is not nullish value, then `clearInterval`

```
let theData = null;
let timeout = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        theData = await gRating.loadData(request_code);
        if (theData) {
            clearInterval(timeout);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        respondWithError(res, "API error", 500);
    }
}, 2000);
```